# How to replicate a div multiple fixed no of times

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

I want to replicate the the whole div multiple no of times(i.e; on A4 paper size Upperleftcorner,UpperRight Corner,Bottom left corner ,Bottom right corner)

```
    <script language="javascript" type='text/javascript'>
    function updateDivs() {
     var repeat_container = document.getElementById("layout");
     var div_element;

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        div_element = document.createElement("div");
        repeat_container.appendChild(div_element);
      }
    }
   </script>


  <div class = "layout">
 <div class="header"><asp:label id="label1" runat="server/></div>
   <div class="chart"><asp:label id="label2" runat="server/></div>
    <div class="legend"><asp:label id="label3" runat="server/></div>
     <div class="info1"><asp:label id="label4" runat="server/></div>
      <div class="info2"><asp:label id="label5" runat="server/></div>
      <div class="info3"><asp:label id="label6" runat="server/></div>............
  </div>

  ![enter image description here][1]
  the screen shot is attached below
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it with javascript because you have asp.net controls.
  For your each div add `runat="server"` and change their `ID to Upperleftcorner, Upperrightcornerbottom, bottomleftcorner, bottomrightcorner.`

Code:

```
          List<HtmlGenericControl> alldivs=new List<HtmlGenericControl>(4);
            alldivs.Add(Upperleftcorner);
            alldivs.Add(Upperrightcornerbottom);
            alldivs.Add(bottomleftcorner);
            alldivs.Add(bottomrightcorner); 
            foreach(HtmlGenericControl divparent in alldivs)
            {
            HtmlGenericControl divholder= new HtmlGenericControl("div");
            divholder.Attributes.Add("class", "layout");
            for(int i=1;i<=6;i++)
            {
            HtmlGenericControl div= new HtmlGenericControl("div");
            if(i==1)
            div.Attributes.Add("class", "header");
            if(i==2)
            div.Attributes.Add("class", "chart");
            if(i==3)
            div.Attributes.Add("class", "legend");
            if(i==4)
            div.Attributes.Add("class", "info1");
            if(i==5)
            div.Attributes.Add("class", "info2");
            if(i==6)
            div.Attributes.Add("class", "info3");
            Label l=new Label();
            div.Controls.Add(l);
            divholder.Controls.Add(div);
            }
            divparent.Controls.Add(divholder);
            }
```

With javascript you will have to use `<span>`

```
<script language="javascript" type='text/javascript'>
    function updateDivs() {
     var repeat_container = document.getElementById("layout");
     var div_element='<div class = "layout"><div class="header"><span  class="label1" /></div><div class="chart"><span  class="label2" /></div><div class="legend"><span  class="label3" /></div><div class="info1"><span  class="label4" r/></div><div class="info2"><span  class="label5" /></div><div class="info3"><span class="label6" /></div></div>';

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        div_element = document.createElement("div");
        repeat_container.appendChild(div_element);
      }
    }
   </script>
```

Comment: Hey ashwin ,I have already used a Htmlgeneric control,it the data is in multiple(i.e; i am passing the data in the form of list),it gives me the perfect otput as what i expected ,but the problem is ,the main layout i want to repeat multiple no of times (i.e; Upperleft corner,Upperright corner,bottom leftcorner,bottom right corner.)

Comment: I am trying to do this with  something like this<br/> <script language="javascript" type='text/javascript'>
    function updateDivs() {
        var repeat_container = document.getElementById("layout");
        var div_element;

        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            div_element = document.createElement("div");
            repeat_container.appendChild(div_element);
        }
    }
</script>    @Sudippal

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant by "to repeat multiple no of times (i.e; Upperleft corner,Upperright corner,bottom leftcorner,bottom right corner.)"

Comment: Post the screenshot here in the question.

Comment: I think you didn't get me what i am trying to say, see the screenshot, i want the same image to be reflected multiple time..with the above code no doubt all the child controls would be placed under parent control,mine actual concern I have to repeat the actual image multiple times without writing extra lines of code..

Comment: I also know,without the code the whole layout cannot be repeated,but  what i am trying to do is replicate(repeat) the whole div ,without writing extra line of code or creating additional controls

Comment: How can you repeat without code, if your controls are ASP.NET controls? Any ways I used <span> and updated the answer.

Comment: hey ashwin thanks for your suggestion ,what i did is created an usercontrol and within the foreach loop I making this replica of laout

Comment: Glad, you got a solution. If my answer was of any help, than mark it and close the question.